# pass record id to href

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing, href

I want to pass a selected record ID to href link, and have been struggling on the syntax.  Please help!  Here is the case:

1. I can get the selected record id by using: 
   `var id = $('[name="RadioRequest"]:checked').prop('id');`
2. I know following href works: 
   `<a href="/Samples/Create?id=@Model.id" class="btn btn-primary btn">Add Sample</a>`
3. However, how do I combine two together? There is no view-level variable that I can pass
   `var id = $('[name="RadioRequest"]:checked').prop('id')` into the href.

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Do you want to change the `href`-attribute of a `<a />` when you change a radiobutton or checkbox?

Comment: I think you need to explain exactly what you are trying to do a little better.  Also, what have you already tried to do?

Comment: I don't get your question.. You have backend code inside your anchor tag (@Model.id).. you need to show us the html you have in the code

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your comments. I want to use href to pass the id to the create method in the controller "samples", there is view associated with the controller. The id that I need to pass is from selected row. I know how to get the id by using ajax: var id =$('[name="RadioRequest"]:checked').prop('id'); However, how can I pass the id into href?  I can use ?id=@Model.id in href and it works.  Thanks again.